# Symfony2 data-prototype replace value of checkbox

Tags: javascript, symfony

I'm attempting to find an elegant solution to rendering a value of a data prototype checkbox.

Currently there are only placeholders rendered for label and name.

```
<label class="checkbox required" for="foobar_form_networkDetails_programList___name__">
    <input type="checkbox" id="foobar_form_networkDetails_programList___name__" name="foobar_form[networkDetails][programList][__name__]" required="required" value="1" />__name__label__
</label>
```

So I end up with

```
programPrototype = programListContainer.data('prototype');
programRow       = programPrototype.replace(/__name__label__/g, programType);
programRow       = programRow.replace(/__name__/g, programListIndex);
```

I could string replace value="1" but this screams a hack. I would preferably like to replace a placeholder value.

So my options are:

- Render the data-prototype string to the DOM and perform the manipulation on the DOM to reset the value to what I want it to be.
- Override the prototype rendering (I'm not sure how to do this).

This seems like a pretty common scenario, so I am wondering what am I missing?

Comment: If you want to replace `value="1"` why dont you create a variable like you did for `__name__label__` and `__name__`? Otherwise, yes you could manipulate the DOM and modify the value property

Comment: I didn't create those placeholders. They are a part of the default twig theme.

Comment: they actually aren't part of the Twig Theme, they are part of how subforms are rendered by the form component.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of a checkbox should not be done in the prototype, but in the classes that creates the prototype.

Those prototypes are build from some sort of Type class which tells the Form Component how a form should be build. What you need to do is change this configuration and set [the value option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html#value) of the checkbox type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I am not rendering the form checkboxes using Form component, only the data prototype. The checkboxes are created dynamically. So if I understand you correctly, my best option is to render the prototype checkbox to the DOM and apply the value change on the DOM itself (I was trying to avoid this since it's ugly I have to render it then apply selectors to find the checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you cannot use anyone beside boolean (0/1) values in checkboxes per Symfony.

Thanks for the answer(s).